# Problem with combo box using selenium doesn't change the second option

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am doing web scraping to this page https://www.tudrogueriavirtual.com/ and when Selenium do the first charge to the page, I need to select the state and the city, I tried using .click

```
select_state = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ship-state"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
select_state_c = driver.find_element('xpath', '//select[@id="ship-state"]/option[@value="Bogotá, D.C."]').click()
time.sleep(1)
select_state = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ship-state"]').click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu85n.png)

And this not working. I also tried using .select but this didnt work

```
select_state = Select(driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ship-state"]'))
select_state.select_by_value("Bogotá, D.C.")
time.sleep(1)
```

This occurred when I execute my code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBq3.png)

And this is what the page suposed show me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOKjB.png)

this is my Selenium version selenium==4.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `send_keys` like this.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.tudrogueriavirtual.com/")
time.sleep(1)

state = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ship-state')
state.send_keys('Bogotá')
state.click()
time.sleep(1)

city = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ship-city')
city.send_keys('Bogotá, D.c.')
city.click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'nextBtn.btn-ubicacion').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btnFinalizar')[1].click()
```

However rather than use `time.sleep()` I would recommend using the built in waits see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thank you, the program already is correct with your solution. 
I want to ask you a question, ¿why did you use .send_keys('Bogotá') and not .send_keys('Bogotá, D.C.')? I ask you because in the HTML y see that the Value of the option is 'Bogotá, D.C.'.

Comment: My mistake `Bogotá, D.C.` is the correct value